# Haskell recursively applying function to every element but first?

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion, optimization

So I've been doing this program which receives a function `f`, a number `a` and a list `b` and it should return a list `[a, f(a,b), f(f(a,b),b, ..]` iterating through the list `b` and using recursion. Do you guys know how I can optimize my code?

```
calculate :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a]
help :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a]

help f a (x:xs) = (f a x) : (calculate f (f a x) xs)
help f a [] = []

calculate f a b = a : (help f a b)
```

Comment: What about `scanl f a (repeat b)`?

Comment: Hint: `doit f (x:xs) = x : do_the_full_recursive_step f xs`

Comment: *"Do you guys know how to optimise my code?"* What do you mean by "optimise"? Have you timed its performance? What are you asking?

Comment: Thank you. @AJFarmar no, I meant a way of shortening it.

Comment: @codingbudgie Use better names and lose some parentheses. Plus, `help = map`. That's everything.

Comment: @AJFarmar: `help` is not `map`, since it uses an accumulator `a` that is each time updated.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah you're right, `help f a b = iterate (flip f b) a`, rather.

Comment: Are you sure this code does what you want it to do?

Comment: isn't your desired function just `scanl`??

Answer (score 2):

`calculate f a b = tail . concatMap (replicate 2) . scanl f a $ b`.

The replicate bit is probably in error. If so, then simply `calculate = scanl`.

This translates the code, as the "`[a, f(a,b), f(f(a,b),b, ..]`" from the text contradicts it (and it contradicts the text itself, which talks of "iterating *through* the list `b`").

Comment: This works perfectly fine if i use it as `calculate f a b = tail . concatMap (replicate 1) . scanl f a $ b`

Comment: OK, but `concatMap (replicate 1)` is the same as `id` and `id . f` is the same as simply `f` itself. And with `replicate 1` you don't need the `tail` either.